# How to read from a .properties file using batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a requirement where i'd like to read values from a .properties file

my properties file `test.properties` content

```
file=jaguar8
extension=txt
path=c:\Program Files\AC
```

From the above file I need to fetch `jaguar` or anything after `=`

Please help me. Thanks

Answer (score 28):

```
For /F "tokens=1* delims==" %%A IN (test.properties) DO (
    IF "%%A"=="file" set file=%%B
)

echo "%file%"
```

hope this could help

Answer (score 23):

```
@echo off  
FOR /F "tokens=1,2 delims==" %%G IN (test.properties) DO (set %%G=%%H)  
echo %file%  
echo %extension%  
echo %path%
```

Note that there is no space after %%H. Else this causes a space to be appended, to file paths for example, and will cause file not found errors when the variables from the property files are used as part of a file path.Struggled for hours because of this!

Comment: It'll not consider comments though; +1 For solution.

Answer (score 11):

A solution with support for comments (# style). See comments in code for explanation.

test.properties:

```
# some comment with = char, empty line below

#invalid.property=1
some.property=2
some.property=3
# not sure if this is supported by .properties syntax
text=asd=f
```

properties-read.bat:

```
@echo off

rem eol stops comments from being parsed
rem otherwise split lines at the = char into two tokens
for /F "eol=# delims== tokens=1,*" %%a in (test.properties) do (

    rem proper lines have both a and b set
    rem if okay, assign property to some kind of namespace
    rem so some.property becomes test.some.property in batch-land
    if NOT "%%a"=="" if NOT "%%b"=="" set test.%%a=%%b
)

rem debug namespace test.
set test.

rem do something useful with your vars

rem cleanup namespace test.
rem nul redirection stops error output if no test. var is set
for /F "tokens=1 delims==" %%v in ('set test. 2^>nul') do (
    set %%v=
)
```

output from `set test.` (see above):

```
test.some.property=3
test.text=asd=f
```

The most important parts are:

- the `for`-loop with the `eol` and `delims` option and
- the `if`-checks that both variables `%%a` and `%%b` are set.

What you do in the `for`-loop with the variable and its value is certainly up to you - assigning to some prefixed variables was just an example. The namespacing approach avoids that any other global variable gets overridden. 
For example if you have something like `appdata` defined in your .properties file.

I'm using this to get rid of an extra config.bat and instead using one .properties file for both the java app and some support batch files.

Works for me, but certainly not every edge case is covered here, so improvements welcome!

Answer (score 7):

Try this

```
echo off
setlocal
FOR /F "tokens=3,* delims=.=" %%G IN (test.properties) DO ( set %%G=%%H )

rem now use below vars
if "%%G"=="file"
 set lfile=%%H
if "%%G"=="path"
 set lpath=%%H
if "%%G"=="extension"
 set lextention=%%H
echo %path%

endlocal
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is ancient post but I would like to expand on toschug's great answer.

If the path in the .properties file would be defined as %~dp0 or any other variable that needs to be expanded first before using it, I recommend doing it the following way:
In the .properties file:

```
path=%~dp0
```

In the batch file you can then use it the following way (the code is to be used between the two for(s) defining one <=> cleanup one):

```
if "!test.path!" NEQ "" (
   echo Not expanded path: !test.path!
   call :expand !test.path! test.path
)

echo test.path expanded: !test.path!
pause

:expand
SET "%~2=%~1"
GOTO :EOF
```

Don't forget to use (at the start of the batch file):

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
@ECHO OFF
@SETLOCAL
FOR /F "tokens=1* delims==" %%A IN (test.properties) DO (
ECHO %%A   =    %%B 
)
@ENDLOCAL
```