# Passing a string from config properties file into bat file

Tags: java, properties, batch-file

Need help.

I have one config properties file which has a string.

I need to pass this string into a Batch file.

What is the procedure to do so?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What have you tried? Consider reading [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7708681/how-to-read-from-a-properties-file-using-batch-script                                        Please see the above post it may solve your issue

Answer (score 1):

1) read config file (search how to read file)

2) use Runtime.exec() function look here: [Java Runtime.exec()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8595748/java-runtime-exec)