# Read a file and obtain a value from it in batch script

Tags: windows, file, batch-file

I have a set of servers wherein there is a file in a location called "archive.info" in all servers. I have the following data in the file:

```
#Fri, 14 Feb 2014 20:57:23 -0500

buildname=coreCode_714_317
builddate=2014-02-14 20.57 EST
majorversion=06
minorversion=01
```

I want to create a batch script which can read the buildname from the file and display the output. I use psexec to run remote commands which I could use to  redirect the result to a file.

Could you please help me with creating a batch script which can read the build name and display itplease?

Thanks
Amrith

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to read from a .properties file using batch script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7708681/how-to-read-from-a-properties-file-using-batch-script)

Answer (score 1):

This will read the file one line at a time, ignoring any line that starts with a `#`, and creating variables from the contents of archive.info

```
for /f "eol=# tokens=*" %%A in (archive.info) do set "%%A"
```

Since your lines are in the format `variable=value`, the code effectively runs

```
set buildname=coreCode_714_317
set builddate=2014-02-14 20.57 EST
set majorversion=06
set minorversion=01
```

and you can now use all four variables in your batch script. The quotes are there to preserve the spaces in `builddate`.

Answer (score 0):

if you are interested only in one value:

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%i in ('findstr /i /b "buildname=" archive.info') do set "%%i"
```

If you need more values, I'd prefer SomethingDarks answer.