# Getting values from properties file into batch file

Tags: batch-file

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL
For /F "tokens=1* delims==" %%A IN (build.properties) DO (
    IF "%%A"=="projectPath" set lprojectPath=%%B
    IF "%%A"=="warSourcePath" set lwarSourcePath=%%B
    IF "%%A"=="warDestinationPath" set lwarDestinationPath=%%B
    IF "%%A"=="serverPath" set lserverPath=%%B
)

echo "%lprojectPath%"
echo "%lwarSourcePath%"
echo "%lwarDestinationPath%"
echo "%lserverPath%"
```

I have a properties file named build.properties(key=value). when I run the above bat file echo prints "" an empty string in cmd and I am not able to use the variable values else where in the bat file. I am I making any mistake in retrieval of values from properties file.

```
projectPath = D:\DEV_R4.6_bat_test\brsint-web\brisnt-scheduling
warSourcePath = D:\DEV_R4.6_bat_test\brsint-web\brsint-webapp\target\Bristow.war
warDestinationPath = D:\apache-tomcat-7.0_1.2Latest (2)\webapps
serverPath = D:\apache-tomcat-7.0_1.2Latest (2)\bin
```

This is my properties file.

Comment: please refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7709285/6448640)

Comment: If we could see your `build.properties` file (please edit it into your question) then we may be able to assist better.

Comment: The `==` comparison is _case sensitive_. Use `… do (set l%%A=%%B)` instead of all that `IF`s. Then, check  variables using `set l`

Comment: I added my properties file contents please find it

Comment: I would suggest changing the structure of the properties file, if possible, to remove the whitespace adjacent to the `=`. _(At the moment your `If` looks like this expanded, `IF "serverPath "=="serverPath" set lserverPath= D:\DEV_R4.6_bat_test\brsint-web\brisnt-scheduling`)_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a similar setup for a `name=value` .ini I use,

```
FOR /f %%a IN (db.ini) DO SET %%a
```

`%%a` expands after the `SET` command as `name=value`, thus creating the variable. eg; `SET name=value`

If the "l" character is essential write the line with the "l" preceding the parameter:

```
FOR /f %%a IN (build.properties) DO SET l%%a
```

Comment: this was a good answer, before OP included the actual content of the file.

Answer (score 0):

uh - there are spaces in your `build.properties`. Spaces are critical with the `set` command. Use:

```
@echo off
setlocal 
for /f "tokens=1,* delims== " %%a in (build.properties) do set "l%%a=%%b"
REM note the space in delims
set l
```

Your original code defines variables like `%projectPath %` (note the space) with contents like `<SPACE>D:\DEV_R4.6_bat_test\brsint-web\brisnt-scheduling`